# Solicitud HTTP a API

Tags: api, windows-forms, http

Estoy haciendo una app con windows forms en la cual mediante un botón se realice un solicitud a HTTP a una [API](https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales).

El problema es que no me trae nada, un espacio en blanco entiendo que la api es un array de objetos "casa".

Esta sería mi clase entidad que representa al objeto casa (en este caso estoy tratando de traer el "nombre" solamente)

```
public class Casa
{
    [JsonPropertyName("nombre")]
    public string nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Formulario:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button1_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string apiUrl = "https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales";


        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage respuesta= await httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);


        if (respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            
            string json = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            
            Casa[] casa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Casa[]>(json);

            label1.Text = casa[1].nombre;

        }
    }
}
```

Solamente estoy probando obtener el nombre de la segunda posición pero no trae nada.

Comment: probaste agarrar el json, y fijarte cual es la clase que c# (porque aqui, de windows forms, no hay nada) te devuelve? y una vez hecho eso, hacer la deserializacion directamente? sin tanto lio?

Comment: el json es un array de objetos Casa, cada Casa contiene los valores y nombres del dolar entre otros datos

Comment: yo no te pregunte eso.. te pregunte si agarraste el json, y dejaste que c# o alguna de los trillones de herramientas que hay, te armaran la clase...

Comment: No entendi bien lo que me habias preguntado. Copie el json y use el pegado especial y el visual me armó automaticamente las clases, desconocía dicha herramienta.
Gracias por solucionarlo.

Comment: bueno y entonces, que tenia mal tu clase?

Comment: yo lo estaba entendiendo como una sola clase "Casa" pero tenia que crear dos clases. Clase "Casa" que contiene las propiedades que queria mostrar y otra clasa "Casa2" que tenia la clase Casa como atributo. Y lo que tenia que retonar  era una lista de "Casas2"